# Implementing a Hash Table (rehash scope error)

Tags: c++, scope, hashtable

I am getting a very strange error in my code. This assignment is for a class I'm taking and essentially we are learning how to implement a hash table. The error i'm getting is when I try and rehash to a larger size. Here's the portion of the code giving me the problem, and I'll explain more fully what the problem is.

```
if(htable->size>=htable->cap)
                    {
                        cout<<htable->cap<<endl;
                        HashTable tempht=*htable;
                        delete htable;
                        htable=new HashTable((tempht.cap * 2) + 1);



                        for (size_t i=0; i<tempht.cap; i++)
                        {

                            Node* n=tempht.table[i];
                            while (n!=NULL)
                            {
                                htable->add(n->item);
                                n=n->next;
                            }
                        }
                        if (htable->table[0]==NULL)
                        {
                            cout<<"HOORAY!"<<endl;
                        }
                    }

                    if (htable->table[0]==NULL)
                    {
                        cout<<"HOORAY!"<<endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout<<htable->table[0]->item<<endl;
                    }
```

`htable` is a `HashTable` variable. In the `HashTable` class it contains an array `Node*` (Nodes are just objects I created that contain a string and a pointer to the next item in the chain). This part of the code is simply trying to rehash to a larger table. The issue I'm getting is once I exit the first if statement, my table's first value no longer equals NULL (the test I'm running rehashes a table with nothing in it to a table that still has nothing in it, but has a larger capacity). When I run the code, the first `htable->table[0]==NULL` passes while the second does not, despite there being no changes other than exiting the if statement (my expected result is that the `table[0]` should be NULL). My best guess is it's some kind of scoping error, but I honestly can't see where the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Just to clarify, the initial hash table has a capacity of 0 (this is one of the project requirements). So when i try to add an item to the table, this if statement is executed (since the size is 0 and the cap is 0, we have to maintain a load factor of 1). I can confirm that once the table reaches the first and second "Hooray" checks, that `htable->cap` (which is the total capacity of the array) is 1, which is what it should be. The only thing that is getting messed is bucket 0 (which in this case is the only bucket). For whatever reason, it's null before exiting the if statement but not after.

I'm posting my whole `HashTable` class, let me know if you find anything.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;
class HashTable
{
public:
    Node** table;
    int size;
    int cap;
    HashTable (int c)
    {
        size=0;
        cap=c;
        table = new Node*[cap];

        if (cap>0)
        {

            for (size_t i=0; i<cap; ++i)
            {
                table[i]=NULL;


            }
        }
    }
    ~HashTable()
    {
        delete table;
    }
    size_t hash(string thing)
    {
        size_t total=0;
        int asci;
        char c;
        size_t index;

        for (size_t i=0; i<thing.length(); i++)
        {
            total=total*31;
            c=thing[i];
            asci=int(c);

            total=asci+total;

        }

        index=total%cap;
                    cout<<"index"<<index<<endl;
            system("pause");

        return index;
    }
    void add(string thing)
    {


            size_t index;
            index=hash(thing);
                        cout<<"index "<<index<<endl;
            system("pause");
            Node* temp=table[index];
            if (temp==NULL)
            {
            cout<<"Here"<<endl;
            system("pause");
            }
            else
            {
                            cout<<"Here2"<<endl;
            system("pause");
                        cout<<"temp"<<temp->item<<endl;
            system("pause");
            }
            Node* n = new Node(thing);
            cout<<"n"<<n->item<<endl;
            system("pause");
            if (temp==NULL)
            {

                table[index]=n;
            }
            else
            {
                while (temp->next!=NULL)
                {
                    temp=temp->next;
                }
                temp->next=n;
            }

        size++;
    }
    Node* find(string search)
    {
        Node* n= NULL;
        size_t index;
        if(cap!=0)
        {
        index=hash(search);
        Node* temp=table[index];
        while (temp!=NULL)
        {
            if (temp->item==search)
            {
                n=temp;
                return n;
            }
        }
        }
        return n;
    }
    void remove (string thing)
    {
        if (find(thing)==NULL)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            size_t index;
            index=hash(thing);
            Node* temp=table[index];

            if (temp->item==thing)
            {
                table[index]=temp->next;
                delete temp;
            }
            while (temp->next!=NULL)
            {
              if (temp->next->item==thing)
              {
                  Node* temp2=temp->next;
                  temp->next=temp->next->next;
                  delete temp2;
                  break;
              }

            }
        }
        size--;
    }
    void print(ofstream &ofile)
    {

        for (size_t i=0; i<cap; i++)
        {
            Node* n=table[i];
            ofile<<"hash "<<i<<":";
            while (n!=NULL)
            {
                ofile<<" "<<n->item;
                n=n->next;
            }
        }
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is C++, and I'm more a Java guy, but I'll take a stab at it.

Turns out the problem IS with the

```
                HashTable tempht=*htable;
                delete htable;
```

block after all.

See, the first line there says "copy all of the members from *htable into tempht".  So now tempht and htable SHARE their table memory, since table is just a pointer to memory that was allocated at construction, and you just copied the *pointer*.  You wanted it to copy the nodes inside table, but it didn't do that.

So now you have two different HashTable objects with the same pointer value in table.  Now, when tempht is freed, the destructor calls free on the table pointer, which effectively frees the table data in both objects htable and tempht.

What you really want to do is write a copy constructor, or do something like:

```
HashTable *tempht=htable;
htable=new HashTable((tempht->cap * 2) + 1);
for (size_t i=0; i<tempht->cap; i++)
{

    Node* n=tempht->table[i];
    while (n!=NULL)
    {
        htable->add(n->item);
        n=n->next;
    }
}
if (htable->table[0]==NULL)
{
    cout<<"HOORAY!"<<endl;
}
delete tempht;
```

See how all I've really done is change tempht to a pointer, using it to point to the old hashtable while you copy all the nodes from it to the new htable object, **then** deleting the old Hashtable.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, but i do need to correct a few things. First, tempht is not a pointer. It's an actual hard copy, this way i can free the memory of htable but still use the values it contained. I did try to rename the HOORAY statements and confirmed that it was only the first HOORAY showing up. The other thing is, when im rehashing, the old table has nothing in it so the new one should also have nothing in it, and it does up until it exits the if statement, then for whatever reason, the items are no longer NULL. Once again, thank you for your comments, and keep trying to fix it.

Comment: Ok the hashtable class is posted, ignore the system pauses, i was just tyrying to figure out where the problem was initially.

Comment: Yep this was the problem exactly. While I was stepping through I noticed that the destructor was being called at the end of the if statement and initally and I couldn't figure out why, until I realized it was trying to destroy my tempht object. As soon as you mentioned they shared the same memory block, it made perfect sense what was going on. Your solution works perfect! Thank you so much for your help!